# Why some solutions don't show up as corner points while optimizing functions?

Tags: linear-programming

I was optimizing f(x)=38000-30000x-8000y. Constraints:-
38000x+8000y<=38000
30000x+8000y>=15000 x>=0, y>=0, I Got minimum Values at two corner points (0,1.875) & (0.5,0). But when I did some grunt work I also found that (0.233333333,1) was also a solution. So why this point didn't show up as a corner point in my feasible region?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sir, so did that just means that (0.2333333,1) is not a good solution?or why isn't it good ? And yeah I really don't have learned the simplex algorithm yet, I just plotted my linear equations and then shaded the regions...

Comment: When an LP problem has multiple optimal vertices, then all the points that can be expressed as convex combination of the optimal vertices are also optimal solutions. A necessary condition for having multiple optimal solutions is that  the gradient of the objective function and the gradient of a constraint must be collinear, as in your case.